# How to programmatically invoke text selection UI on TextView?

Tags: android

### Short summary

I have a **context menu** invoked by a **longpress** on a `TextView`, and it is preventing users from selecting text in the `TextView` (since the stock Android text selection UI is also invoked by a **longpress** and my context menu receives the **longpress** event before the text selector does).

### Details

I have a `ListView` with a number or custom row views. Inside each row view is a `TextView` which displays a user comment. Each `TextView` has `android:textIsSelectable="true"`.

In order to allow the user to edit their comment, I am using a **context menu** (that contains an "Edit Comment" menu item) that is invoked when the user performs a **longpress** on the row.

However, I would also like users to have the option of selecting text in the comment. The problem is that, both the stock Android text-selection UI and my **context menu** are both invoked by a **longpress** on the comment, and my **context menu** consumes the **longpress** event first.

What I would like to do is add a "Select Text" menu option to my **context menu** that would **(a)** select all the comment text and, **(b)** bring up the Android text selection UI.

But, I have been unable to find a way to programmatically make Android bring up the text selection UI.

To be clear : I do not simply want to select the text and put it in the clipboard. I want the user to see the text highlighted in blue, with the standard Android text selection handles / carets on it so they can manipulate the selected text area themselves.

E.g.: I would like to do the following (this method is in a `Fragment`):

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.select_text:

            // Here I would like to select all text in the comment
            // and bring up the text selection UI

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have tried the following without success :

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =  
    (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

TextView comment = (TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
comment.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
comment.requestFocus();
comment.setSelectAllOnFocus(false);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you can't select a TextView that is inside a ListView, because ListView overrides TextView functionality. You can only click it but not select the words. I think a possible way to achieve this is when you click edit, you transform that TextView into an EditText by setting the visibility to gone and visible... If you need more help with that and think it's a good way to solve your problem, tell me so that I post it as an answer with more details.

Comment: @HusseinElFeky It's possible to select text in a TextView nested in a ListView. My app had that functionality working prior to me adding the longpress-context-menu. Just need to set `android:textIsSelectable="true"`. The issue is that the context menu consumes the longpress event before the text selector receives it.

Comment: Though not a full solution to this problem, I did find that double-tapping on the text you want to select brings up the copy/paste controls. The selection-handles will appear around the word you double-tapped on. Not as elegant as being able to invoke the copy/paste controls from the context menu, and will likely need to inform your users explicitly that they need to double-tap to select text, but at least there is a way to provide text copying functionality.

Comment: There any news to handle that ?